# What happens to my Google Cloud trial credits after trial ends

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm currently using the GCP free 12 month trial. But what happens to my trial credits after the trial ends? Do they expire? Or do I keep them?

Comment: They expire after the 12 month trial period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your free trial ends when you use all of your credit, or after 12 months, whichever happens first.

Answer (score 8):

Earlier answers are now outdated. As of August 17, 2020 new terms state that "users now have 90 days to use their $300 USD in Google Cloud credits." After 90 days any unused credits will expire.

For full details please see Supplemental Terms and Conditions For Google Cloud Platform Free Trial which can be found at https://cloud.google.com/terms/free-trial

Answer (score 0):

"Any remaining, unexpired free trial credit remains in your account."
See: https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#end